# Installing Linux on old Vista Machine

Tags: linux, command-line, windows-vista

I have an old Vista Laptop that will not boot. It is **not** offering Recovery options however, that is not an issue since I don't really need anything from it. I have used a freeware program to get command line access. Is there anyway I can remove everything from this machine and install Linux fresh using just the command line? Right now, if I do an `ls` to view the home directory I see:

bin
drivers
lib
removable
scripts
dev
etc
and so on...

I am average on the command line but can follow instructions well.

Comment: Just boot with a bootable Linux cd or usb and install no need to remove anything you can format during the install

Comment: What freeware program did you use to get "access" to the old laptop? The files you describe, "bin lib dev etc" sound like the root listing of linux. `ls` is also a linux command... It doesn't sound like you mounted & read the actual hard drive. If there are any files you *think* you *might possibly someday* want to see again, you should copy them **before** installing Linux - it may be extremely difficult or impossible after. See https://www.distrowatch.com for listings of hundreds of Linux distros to search/sort/pick from, try them live before installing

Answer (score 0):

As SeanClt said in comments, just format the entire drive during the install.

For your machine, I'd recommend Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Seanclt and Android Dev are correct .

Any bootable Linux distribution should allow you to boot and format your drive.